# Javascript function that Shuffle/Random an array excluding given index

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
const questions = [
    {
      questionText: <img src={`img//${question[0].image}`} />,
      answerOptions: [
        { answerText: <img src={`img/${answer[Math.floor(Math.random() * 11)].image}`} />, isCorrect: false },
        { answerText: <img src={`img/${answer[Math.floor(Math.random() * 11)].image}`} />, isCorrect: false },
        { answerText: <img src={`img/${answer[0].image}`} />, isCorrect: true },
        { answerText: <img src={`img/${answer[Math.floor(Math.random() * 11)].image}`} />, isCorrect: false },
      ]
    }
]
```

For example in the quiz  array, instead of Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) which generates number from 0 to 11, it should exclude 0 index so that answer list is not same. Also how to have the other answers with different index number.

Comment: Do not pick one random item at a time - shuffle your array first, and then pick items from the shuffled array one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Use `splice` to remove the correct answer from the array, then shuffle, then use `splice` again to insert the element back:

```js
function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
    }
}

const answerOptions = [
        { answerText: 'A', isCorrect: false },
        { answerText: 'B', isCorrect: false },
        { answerText: 'C', isCorrect: true },
        { answerText: 'D', isCorrect: false },
]

const correctAnswerIndex = answerOptions.findIndex(answer => answer.isCorrect);
const removed = answerOptions.splice(correctAnswerIndex, 1);
shuffleArray(answerOptions);
answerOptions.splice(correctAnswerIndex, 0, ...removed);
console.log(answerOptions);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply.  How can i use /call this logic. Also questions array[{},{},{}] can have multiple objects

Comment: I didn't understand